# I can't get links to parent parent page to work on a Jekyll webpage

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

I apologize because I think I'm missing something very obvious here, but when I make sub-categories in the Jekyll hierarchy this is how I've done it so far.

My root directory being karrots_page, I'll have a structure like this
`karrots_page/articles`

and within the questions directory, I'll have a few markdown pages like

1. articles.md
2. happiness-is.md
3. boring-questions.md

fun-questions.md and boring-questions.md will have front matter like

```
---
layout: page
title: Happiness is?!
permalink: /happiness-is/
parent: articles 
---
```

and the `articles.md` named after the directory it's in `/karrots_page/articles` will have a front matter like this

```
---
layout: page
title: articles
permalink: /articles/
has_children: true
---
```

and although that works, once I am within one of the article pages I can't get the link at the top to navigate back to the `articles.md` the main page, I just get a 404 when I click [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDlwG.png) link

The other strange thing is I have this all set up and working on another site in which there is a page that goes two levels down `/karrots_notes/questions/1000-questions` where every page directly nested in the /questions directory can successfully navigate back to the /questions directory with the top link, but when you go deeper down into a page in 1000-questions directory, when you click the top link to go back to the list of 1000-questions pages, it just takes you to the homepage of the site.

*on top of that* when I add the whole of the `/questions/` directory to the site where the navigation links don't work, all of the sudden the navigation links *do* work for my articles directory.

I have a feeling I'm not doing something right with the markdown front matter, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Can you provide code you use for breadcrumb ?

Comment: I didn't make any code for the breadcrumbs, I didn't even know that list of higher level pages was called breadcrumbs.  I thought the breadcrumbs were made by being inside of a directory inside of the root, like `root/articles/happiness.md` will automatically have a breadcrumb for the articles.md (inside of articles directory) on the happiness.md page because it's inside the articles directory.  I'm not altogether sure how breadcrumbs are made in Jekyll.

Comment: having the exact same issue! have you found any way to solve this? The strange thing is: it is only this way when I build the page. Just serving it during local development: no issue :/